# Given two strings, find the longest common bag of chars

Tags: string, algorithm

This question is slightly different from the kind of finding longest sequence or substring from two strings.

Given two string of the same size N, find the longest substrings from each string such that the substrings contains the same bag of chars.

The two substrings may not necessarily have the same sequence. But they must have the same bag of chars.

For example,

a = ABCDDEGF
b = FPCDBDAX

The longest matching bag of chars are ABCDD (ABCDD from a, CDBDA from b)

How to solve this problem?

---

**UPDATE**

The goal is to find substrings from each input string, such that they have the same bag of chars. By saying "substring", they must be consecutive chars.

---

**Update**: Initially I thought of a dynamic programming approach. It works as below.

To compare two bags of chars of the same length K, it would take O(K) time to achieve so. Convert each string into a shorten form:

```
ABCDDEGF -> A1B1C1D2E1G1F1
FPCDBDAX -> A1B1C1D2F1P1X1
```

The shorten form is sorted alphabets followed by number of frequencies in the string. 
Construct, sort, and compare the shorten forms would take O(K) time in total. (Implementation can be achieved by using an array of chars though)

Two bags of chars are equal iif their shorten forms have the same chars and respective frequencies.

In addition, it takes O(logK) time to find the difference chars between the two string.

Now, for two input strings:

1. If their shorten forms are identical, then this is the longest common bag of chars.
2. Find chars in string1 such that they do not appear in string2. Tokenize string1 into several substrings based on those chars.
3. Find chars in string2 such that they do not appear in string1. Tokenize string2 into several substrings based on those chars.
4. Now, we have two list of strings. Compare each pair (which in turn is the same problem with a smaller size of input) and find the longest common bag of chars.

The worst case would be O(N<sup>3</sup>), and best case would be O(N). Any better idea?

Comment: It looks like you're using count sort for the "shorten form" - you can only use it if you know the range of your characters. Next, you aren't really using the count, only as a way of checking what characters are present. As for point 4 - it isn't a smaller problem input. Given `abbbbbb` and `aaaaaaaaab`, you cannot eliminate any letter. Further, the count of the characters gives you very little information, especially when you don't know K from the start.

Comment: @Kobi: Chars are ranged integers. For example, ASCII would be in range 0 - 128. It will be more tricky to allow Unicode chars. We need the frequency count to test "equality" the two shorten forms.

Comment: So, are you checking for every sub-string in all lengths?

Comment: I'm sorry - isn't it `ab`, or am I not understanding the question?

Comment: @Kobi: Initially the two input strings have the same length. It is possible that after tokenization we will face two strings of different length... you are right. I am thinking a solution to your question.

Comment: @SiLent SoNG: Did the interviewer happen to say where such an algorithm is actually used?

Comment: @Lazer: It's not my interview qns. I got it from a friend who recently attempted it.

Comment: Could this question be tagged with "string" tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a set of the characters present in `a`, and another of the characters present in `b`. Walk through each string and strike (e.g., overwrite with some otherwise impossible value) all the characters not in the set from the other string. Find the longest string remaining in each (i.e., longest string of only "unstruck" characters).

Edit: Here's a solution that works roughly as noted above, but in a rather language-specific fashion (using C++ locales/facets):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>

struct filter : std::ctype<char> {
    filter(std::string const &a) : std::ctype<char>(table, false) {
        std::fill_n(table, std::ctype<char>::table_size, std::ctype_base::space);

        for (size_t i=0; i<a.size(); i++) 
            table[(unsigned char)a[i]] = std::ctype_base::upper;
    }
private:
    std::ctype_base::mask table[std::ctype<char>::table_size];
};

std::string get_longest(std::string const &input, std::string const &f) { 
    std::istringstream in(input);
    filter *filt = new filter(f);

    in.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), filt));

    std::string temp, longest;

    while (in >> temp)
        if (temp.size() > longest.size())
            longest = temp;
    delete filt;
    return longest;
}

int main() { 
    std::string a = "ABCDDEGF",  b = "FPCDBDAX";
    std::cout << "A longest: " << get_longest(a, b) << "\n";
    std::cout << "B longest: " << get_longest(b, a) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Edit2: I believe this implementation is O(N) in all cases (one traversal of each string). That's based on `std::ctype<char>` using a table for lookups, which is O(1). With a hash table, lookups would also have O(1) expected complexity, but O(N) worst case, so overall complexity would be O(N) expected, but O(N<sup>2</sup>) worst case. With a set based on a balanced tree, you'd get O(N lg N) overall.

Comment: What if there are very few (or no) impossible characters?  The problem you have "left" is just as bad as the original, and you have not stated a solution for that part.

Comment: @Ether: This can be dealt with about a dozen different ways. One is to convert the characters to some other type with a greater range, so you have "spare" values to use. Another is to use a slightly different algorithm, such as separating the string into sub-strings instead of just "striking out" the values you don't care about.

Comment: I would just sort and walk, advancing the second index on a non-match and storing and advancing both indexes on a match. Especially since both arrays are the same lenght

Comment: @Jason: at least if I understand what you're getting at, I don't think that works. For example, both example strings contain "F", but it's not part of the longest substring (i.e., in both cases it's separate from any common character).

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: True. I had overlooked that F bit. Also, didn't see Jason Coco's comment.

Comment: Can we do something like creating ascii char values array of two strings and than match two arrays for common ascaii values.

Comment: Say you have, after striking the chars (impossible being x)
X = xxBABAxx
Y = xAxBBxAx
The longest bag is 1, 'A' or 'B'.
It seems your algorithm would return 'BB'.

Comment: @ring0: yes, my algorithm with return "BABA" and "BB". At least as I read the question, that's what he wants (e.g., his example of "ABCDD").

Comment: @Jerry: yes, but ABCDD letters and CDBDA letters are, both, in the same "bag", as consecutive letters. While BB on one side is not found in any of the BABA "bags". In other terms, taking one bag of consecutive letters from string X and one bag from string Y, they "match" if at least one permutation of X is Y.
This is how I understand the problem.

Comment: @ring0: you could easily be right, and if so it would certainly require a different algorithm than I've used.

Comment: Have to -1 as you're neglecting the "frequency" components of the elements in the bag.  A "bag" is a proper math term, meaning the same as "multiset" -- a set where each element carries a count/multiplicity/frequency, and according to my interpretation of the problem, these counts are required to match.  I believe you're answering a slightly different question, where "bag" has been replaced with "set", which makes the problem much easier.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: that is, of course, your privilege. Given how many people have understood the question in different ways, I think if a downvote is merited, it should go to the original question. Even after four or five revisions, the goal does not seem entirely clear.

Comment: @Jerry: The original question could have been phrased more clearly, though I think the latest update clarifies things.  I realise you answered before that, and it's annoying when an OP edits the question afterwards.  If you answer the question as currently posed, I'll of course +1.

Answer (score 4):

Just a note to say that this problem will not admit a "greedy" solution in which successively larger bags are constructed by extending existing feasible bags one element at a time.  The reason is that even if a length-k feasible bag exists, there need not be any feasible bag of length (k-1), as the following counterexample shows:

```
ABCD
CDAB
```

Clearly there is a length-4 bag (`A:1, B:1, C:1, D:1`) shared by the two strings, but there is no shared length-3 bag.  This suggests to me that the problem may be quite hard.

Comment: Mega-ouch!  I was looking at a greedy approach but you showed it doesn't work.  Lacking a greedy approach it looks like there can't be an answer under O(n!) runtime.

Comment: Well, there's always the O(n^4) brute-force approach of comparing every substring of A with every substring of B.  And there could be a divide-and-conquer or dynamic programming approach I'm not seeing.  Also I'm pretty sure a faster solution should be possible for small alphabets (e.g. binary).  Would be nice to think about this more but I gotta do some real work now! :)

Answer (score 2):

lets look at this problem like this.. this solution is going to more optimized and will be very easy to code but read through the def and you **MUST read the code** to get the idea... else it will just sound crazy and complex

**THINK ABOUT THIS**

in your questions the 2 example strings you gave lets take them as two set, i.e {x,y,z}, of characters...

AND.. AND... your resulting substring(set) will be one with **characters** common in both strings(sets) and will be **continuous entries** and the qualifying substring(ser) will be one with **highest number of entries**

above are a few properties of the result but will only work if used via the following algorithm\methodolgy

we have two sets

a = { BAHYJIKLO }

b = { YTSHYJLOP }

Take

a **U** b = { - , - , H , Y , J , - , - , L , O }

b **U** a = {Y , - , - , H , Y , J , L , O , -}

its just that i have **replaced** the characters who **didn't qualify for union set** with a "**-**" or any special\ignored character

doing so we have two strings from which we can easily extract `HYJ`,`LO`,`Y`,`HYJLO`

now string\substrings comparisons and different processing takes time so what i do is i write these strings\substrings to a text file with separated by space or different lines.. so that when i read a file i get the whole string instead of having a nested loop to locate a substring or manage temporary variables....

after you have `HYJ`,`LO`,`Y`,`HYJLO` i don't think its a problem to find your desired result....

**NOTE:** if you start processing the strings and sub strings in this with temporary variables and nested loops for first make a sub string then search for it... then its going to be very costly solution... you have to use filing like this...

```
char a[20], b[20]; //a[20] & b[30] are two strings
cin>>a; cin>>b;
int t=0;

open a temporary text file "file1" to write '(built-in-function works here)'
//a U b
for(int x=0; x<length(a); x++)
{
    t=0;

    for(int y=0; y<length(b); x++)
       { if( a[x] == b[y]) t=1; }

    if(t == 1)
       { 
          write 'a[x]' to the file1 '(built-in-function works here)'
          t=0;
       }
    else
       write a 'space' to the file1 '(built-in-function works here)'
}

//b U a
for(int x=0; x<length(a); x++)
{
    t=0;

    for(int y=0; y<length(b); x++)
       { if( b[x] == a[y]) t=1; }

    if(t == 1)
       {
         write 'a[x]' to the file1 '(built-in-function works here)'
         t=0;
       }
    else
       write a 'space' to the file1 '(built-in-function works here)'
}
/*output in the file wil be like this
_____FILE1.txt_____
  HYJ  LO Y HYJLO        
*/
//load all words in an array of stings from file '(built-in-function works here)'

char *words[]={"HYJ","LO","Y","HYJLO"};
int size=0,index=0;

for( int x=0; x<length(words); x++)
    for( int y=0; x<length(words); y++)
    {
       if( x!=y && words[x] is a substring of words[y] ) // '(built-in-function works here)'
          {
               if( length(words[x] ) < size )
               {
                     size = length(words[x];
                     index = x;
               }
          }
    }

 cout<< words[x]; 
 //its the desired result.. its pretty old school bu i think you get the idea

}
```

i wrote the code for... its working if you want it gimme you email i will send it to you... b.t.w i like this problem and the complexity of this algo is 3n(square)

Comment: p.s. there is a lot of PSEUDO code type of thingy that's where built in functions will come in... and i wrote the code for TC++...

Comment: p.s. (part2) i have done lexical analysis of C++ with just two loops using this filing method... and so my solutions complexity for the lexical analysis of C++ came out to be 2n :)

Comment: p.s. (part3) for interview questions its a good idea to explain them an algo or a technique instead of bombarding them with a list of built in functions that solve the problem....

Comment: i think i got the last part wrong ... when the words are in File... the longest of them is the required...

Answer (score 1):

Here's my rather anti-pythonic implementation that nevertheless leverages python's wonderful built in sets and strings.

```
a = 'ABCDDEGF'
b = 'FPCDBDAX'

best_solution = None
best_solution_total_length = 0

def try_expand(a, b, a_loc, b_loc):
    # out of range checks
    if a_loc[0] < 0 or b_loc[0] < 0:
        return
    if a_loc[1] == len(a) or b_loc[1] == len(b):
        return


    if set(a[a_loc[0] : a_loc[1]]) == set(b[b_loc[0] : b_loc[1]]):
        global best_solution_total_length, best_solution
        #is this solution better than anything before it?
        if (len(a[a_loc[0] : a_loc[1]]) + len(b[b_loc[0] : b_loc[1]])) > best_solution_total_length:
            best_solution = (a_loc, b_loc)
            best_solution_total_length = len(a[a_loc[0] : a_loc[1]]) + len(b[b_loc[0] : b_loc[1]])


    try_expand(a, b, (a_loc[0]-1, a_loc[1]), (b_loc[0], b_loc[1]))
    try_expand(a, b, (a_loc[0], a_loc[1]+1), (b_loc[0], b_loc[1]))
    try_expand(a, b, (a_loc[0], a_loc[1]), (b_loc[0]-1, b_loc[1]))
    try_expand(a, b, (a_loc[0], a_loc[1]), (b_loc[0], b_loc[1]+1))


for a_i in range(len(a)):
    for b_i in range(len(b)):
        # starts of the recursive expansion from identical letters in two substrings
        if a[a_i] == b[b_i]:
            # if substrings were expanded from this range before then there won't be an answer there
            if best_solution == None or best_solution[0][0] > a_i or best_solution[0][1] <= a_i or best_solution[1][0] > b_i or best_solution[1][1] <= b_i:
                    try_expand(a, b, (a_i, a_i), (b_i, b_i))


print a[best_solution[0][0] : best_solution[0][1]], b[best_solution[1][0] : best_solution[1][1]]
```

Forgot to mention that this is obviously a fairly bruteforce approach and I'm sure there's an algorithm that runs much, much faster.